# bug push javascript doesn't work properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, laravel

I found a bug when entering data into an array with the push method, the bug is that the data enters index 0 (the index is only stuck to 2) can be seen in the following image:

here output from console

[image]

and here is my script :

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        let btn = $("#btn");
        let target = $("#target");
        let genre = $("#genre");

        btn.click(function() {
            target.toggleClass('hidden');
            target.hasClass('hidden') ? btn.text('Opsi Lain') : btn.text('Sembunyikan');
        });

        genre.on('keyup', function() {
            let query = $(this).val();

            if (query != '' || query != null) {
                let autocomplete = $("#genre-list");

                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    url: "http://localhost/autocomplete/fetch",
                    method: "post",
                });

                $.ajax({
                    data: {
                        query: query
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        // console.log(data);
                        autocomplete.fadeIn();
                        autocomplete.html(data);
                    }
                });

            }

        });

        $("form").on('click', 'a', function() {
            let arr = [$("div strong").text()];
            arr.push($(this).text());
            console.log(arr);

            let value = `<strong name="genres" value="${$(this).text()}" class="inline-flex my-1.5 mr-2 bg-cool-gray-300 normal-case text-center rounded-sm pl-1.5 pr-1 h-4 no-underline text-xs py-0 tracking-normal font-normal cursor-pointer box-border items-center">${$(this).text()}<svg data-icon="cross" style="fill: currentcolor;" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="ml-1 w-3 h-3 box-border"><path d="M9.41 8l3.29-3.29c.19-.18.3-.43.3-.71a1.003 1.003 0 00-1.71-.71L8 6.59l-3.29-3.3a1.003 1.003 0 00-1.42 1.42L6.59 8 3.3 11.29c-.19.18-.3.43-.3.71a1.003 1.003 0 001.71.71L8 9.41l3.29 3.29c.18.19.43.3.71.3a1.003 1.003 0 00.71-1.71L9.41 8z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></strong>`;
            genre.before(value);
            genre.val('');
            $("#genre-list").fadeOut();
        });

        $("form").on('click', 'svg', function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    </script>
```

and my form :

```html
<form action="{{ route('private.store') }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <div class="shadow overflow-hidden sm:rounded-md">
                <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white sm:p-6">
                    <div class="ml-12 md:ml-52">
                        <div class="mb-5">
                            <label for="title" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Title</label>
                            <input type="text" value="{{ old('title') }}" name="title" id="title" class="mt-1 form-input w-full md:w-3/6 text-gray-700" placeholder="title anime">
                            @error('title') <p class="mt-1"><span class="px-1 font-semibold rounded-full bg-red-400 text-white"> {{ $message }} </span></p>
                            @enderror
                            @error('genres') <p class="mt-1"><span class="px-1 font-semibold rounded-full bg-red-400 text-white"> {{ $message }} </span></p>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-5">
                            <label for="genre" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Genre</label>
                            <div class="w-full md:w-3/6 inline-flex flex-wrap items-center shadow-sm z-10  appearance-none bg-white border rounded-md text-base px-2 py-2">
                                <input type="text" value="{{ old('genre') }}" name="genre" id="genre" placeholder="What Genre ?" class=" text-gray-700 text-xs tracking-normal leading-4 flex-grow h-7 box-border" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>
                            <div id="genre-list"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-5">
                            <label for="link" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Tempat Nonton</label>
                            <input type="text" name="link" value="{{ old('link') }}" id="link" placeholder="https://nanime.us" class="mt-1 form-input w-full md:w-3/6 text-gray-700">
                            @error('link')
                            <p class="mt-1"><span class="px-1 font-semibold rounded-full bg-red-400 text-white"> {{ $message }} </span></p>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-5">
                            <div class="flex items-start">
                                <div class="flex items-center h-5">
                                    <input id="status" name="status" value=1 type="checkbox" class="focus:ring-indigo-500 h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300 rounded" @if (old('status')) checked @endif>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ml-3 text-sm">
                                    <label for="status" class="font-medium text-gray-700">Perlihatkan ke Public?</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div id="target" class="hidden">
                            <div class="mb-5">
                                <label for="motivasi" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Motivasi</label>
                                <textarea rows="4" name="motivasi" id="motivasi" class="w-full md:w-3/6 resize-none mt-1 form-input text-gray-700">{{ old('motivasi') }}</textarea>
                                @error('motivasi')
                                <p class="mt-1"><span class="px-1 font-semibold rounded-full bg-red-400 text-white"> {{ $message }} </span></p>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="bg-white">
                            <button type="button" id="btn" class="mb-5 inline-flex justify-center py-1 px-2 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                                Opsi Lain
                            </button>
                            <button type="submit" class="mb-5 ml-48 sm:ml-96 md:ml-96 inline-flex justify-center py-1 px-2 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                                Create
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

The strong tag will be generated when the user clicks on an href link and the href link is generated from the controller, along with the contents of the controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class AutocompleteController extends Controller
{
    function fetchGenre(Request $request)
    {
        $query = $request->get('query');

        $kondisi = DB::table('ajax')
            ->where('for', '=', 'genre')
            ->where('value', 'LIKE', "{$query}%")->exists();

        if ($query && $kondisi) {
            $data = DB::table('ajax')
                ->where('for', '=', 'genre')
                ->where('value', 'LIKE', "{$query}%")
                ->get();
            $output =  '<div class="origin-top-right right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 divide-y divide-gray-100">';
            foreach ($data as $row) {
                $output .= '<div class="py-1"> <a href="#" class="pilih block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">'.$row->value.'</a> </div>';
                $output .= '</div>';
                return $output;
            }
        } 
        elseif (!$kondisi) {
            $err =  '<div class="origin-top-right right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 divide-y divide-gray-100">';
            $err .= '<div class="py-1"> <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">Genre tidak di temukan!</a> </div>';
            $err .= '</div>';
            return $err;
        }
        else {
            $kosong = '';
            return $kosong;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `data enters index 0 (the index is only stuck to 2)`  mean? Show CODE, not pictures of something. Console.log in a real example is more useful than a picture of YOUR console log

Comment: you have `let arr = [$("div strong").text()];` then push one more item. you have two items in the array. What is the problem?

Comment: You're creating a new array every time you click on the button, not pushing onto an existing array.

Comment: If you want to keep adding to the array, it should be a global variable, not a local variable in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to the original question, the problem appears to be with

```
 $("div strong").text()
```

This creates an array of jQuery objects containing the the `<strong>` elements  inside a `div` element, and concatenates their text content into a single string.

> `.text()`
>  Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements.

You probably meant to push the text content of *each* `<strong>` element as a separate array entry, using something more like:

```
$("form").on('click', 'a', function() {
    let arr = [];
    $("div strong").each( function () {
        arr.push($(this).text());
    });
    arr.push($(this).text());
    console.log(arr);
});
```

Although untested it may help you see how to program your solution.

Answer (score 0):

**#Solved in the following ways**

[I change the location of the variable from local to global](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q1Jj.png)

I change the location of the variable from local to global

thank you for the intruction :)